# Display search output using json data in react native

Tags: react-native

I am at a very primitive stage of learning react-native. And I am trying to solve a simple problem, which may sound silly, but I really want to know the answer.

I have a json file

**data.js**

```
export const PRODUCT_DATA = [
    {
        name: 'abc',
        price: 90,
        weight: '1 kg',
        currency: 'INR',
        liked: true,
        image: require('../assets/images/carrots/Rectangle238.png')
    },
    {
        name: 'bce',
        price: 10,
        weight: '1 kg',
        currency: 'USD',
        liked: false,
        image: require('../assets/images/mango/Rectangle234.png')
    },
    {
        AllCategoriesComponent: [
            {
                icon: "home-outline",
                name: "Household",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "basket-outline",
                name: "Grocery",
                shape: false,
            },
            {
                icon: "ios-podium",
                name: "Milk",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "ios-rose",
                name: "chilled",
                shape: false,
            },
            {
                icon: "hardware-chip",
                name: "Drinks",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "cloud",
                name: "Pharmacy",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "fast-food",
                name: "Frozen Food",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "football",
                name: "Vegetable",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "bulb",
                name: "Meat",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "football",
                name: "Vegetable",
                shape: true,
            },
            {
                icon: "bulb",
                name: "Meat",
                shape: true,
            },
        ]
    },
    
];
```

ANd below is screen file

**screen.js**

```
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import { Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { PRODUCT_DATA } from "./data";

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            search: '',
        }
    }

    updateSearch = (search) => {
        this.setState({ search: search });
    };
    render() {
        const { search } = this.state;
        return (
            <View>
                <SearchBar onChangeText={this.updateSearch} value={search} />
                {PRODUCT_DATA[2].AllCategoriesComponent.map((item, index) => {
                    if (item.name === this.state.search) {
                        return (
                            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}>
                                <Text>{search}</Text>
                            </View>
                        );
                    } else {
                        return (<Text></Text>);
                    }
                })}
                <Text>{this.state.search}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see this is not a good solution. I am able to print the output only if I type full name in the `SearchBar`. Also it seems all the `item.name` are already on the screen, which comes up when value of search bar matches it. I want to start showing the output as soon as something is typed on the `SearchBar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help please look into it

```
import { FlatList, Text, View, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: "",
      data: [],
    };

    this.arrayholder = [];
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const data = PRODUCT_DATA[2].AllCategoriesComponent.map((item, index) => {
      return item;
    });
    this.setState({ data }, () => {
      this.arrayholder = data;
    });
  }

  searchData(text) {
    const newData = this.arrayholder.filter((item) => {
      const itemData = item.name.toUpperCase();
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });

    this.setState({
      data: newData,
      text: text,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(text) => this.searchData(text)}
          value={this.state.text}
          placeholder="Search Here"
        />

        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.row}>{item.name}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also explain what is happening in `searchData(text)`

Comment: @pratteekshaurya `searchData` function contains `text` as param which user typed on press and filtering `newData` by comparing all items in data with `text` and return which is equivalent and set new data to `state` which reflects on screen

Comment: One more thing. By default all the names are printed on the screen, is there a way to start the page with just the searchbar on it, and the names will only appear which is typed?